# lua-resty-auto-ssl: failed to start sockproc

Tags: lua, lua-table, luarocks, openresty

`==> /etc/openresty/nginx/logs/error.log <==
2016/08/07 02:31:26 [error] 194#0: [lua] start_sockproc.lua:9: auto-ssl: failed to start sockproc, context: init_worker_by_lua*`

I get the aforementioned error after my Nginx instance starts.. Don't know what could be causing it..

It appears I may be missing a dependency is that CORRECT.

Here is the [Docker image repo](https://github.com/globalfoodbook/ngxl), with more information on how I have set things up.

Also, I noticed that sockproc is actually running.. See the images below.

[image: screen shot 2016-08-08 at 09 38 38]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error appears to come from [here](https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl/blob/master/lib/resty/auto-ssl/utils/start_sockproc.lua#L9) which looks to mean that `auto-ssl/shell/start_sockproc` failed to start.

[start_sockproc](https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl/blob/master/lib/resty/auto-ssl/shell/start_sockproc) ends by running [`sockproc`](https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl/blob/master/lib/resty/auto-ssl/shell/start_sockproc#L49).

So presumably that failed. Given that that doesn't ship with lua-resty-auto-ssl my guess would be that you need to get that (or install it at least).

Comment: sockproc appears to be insrall already via the Makefile [here](https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl/blob/master/Makefile#L33)..

Comment: @IkennaOkpala That's `start_socproc` not `sockproc` itself. [This target](https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl/blob/master/Makefile#L64) seems to install it (and is run by the `all` target). Did you run it?

Comment: yeah.. thank for pointing that out.. Yes sockproc is running.. I have attached a screen shot to the description above. Here is a link to the dockjer image repo https://github.com/globalfoodbook/ngxl where I have outlined the dependencies..

Comment: If you run `start_sockproc` yourself what is the exit code? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: What... what does that mean? What happens exactly? What about if you run `bash -x path/to/start_sockproc`?

Comment: Don't exactly know but I have submitted a PR with an attempted fix.. https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl/pull/18 Hopefully, this will lead to a resolution.

Comment: thanks for your support on this. I have since submitted a PR about this.. See it here https://github.com/GUI/lua-resty-auto-ssl/pull/18